# Python sympy produced weired number

Tags: python, sympy

I have this code below and wanted to calculate and replace I=Ia+Ib+Ic with Id, Iq or Io after a matrix transform.

[image]

From the transform I can clearly see Ia+Ib+Ic = sqrt(3)*Io, but the program returned I = 49413911907318.0*sqrt(2)*Io

Can anyone please let me know why?

```py
import sympy
from sympy import *

theta_c, Iq, Id, Io, Vq, Vd, Vo, Va, Vb, Vc, Ia, Ib, Ic = symbols('theta_c Iq Id Io Vq Vd Vo Va Vb Vc Ia Ib Ic')


Tabc_inv = sqrt(2/3)*Matrix([[cos(theta_c), -sin(theta_c), 1/sqrt(2)],[cos(theta_c-2*pi/3), -sin(theta_c-2*pi/3), 1/sqrt(2)],[cos(theta_c+2*pi/3), -sin(theta_c+2*pi/3), 1/sqrt(2)]])

Iabc = Tabc_inv*Matrix([Id,Iq,Io])

Ia = Iabc[0]

Ib = Iabc[1]

Ic = Iabc[2]


I_expanded = Ia + Ib + Ic

I = simplify(I_expanded)

print('\n I =',I)
```

Comment: sorry I am new to this community, just edited this post

Comment: Not knowing well is nothing to be sorry about :). But before, it is strongly recommended to go through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make a good question. Also, please post the information directly into your question. If image is not avoidable (such as in your case), include it in the post rather than a link.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Your example gives me `1.22474487139159*sqrt(2)*Io` which is the same as `sqrt(3)*Io`. What is the version of your SymPy?